# Matching Input Text in HTML parse with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I thought just setting "text=size" would result in the value i need. Maybe I am miss understanding? What am i doing wrong?

```
import requests, re, json, time, sys, os,webbrowser
import subprocess as s
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
global size

size = "Medium"

'''html  = <option selected="selected" data-sku="51728-003" value="660654030868">Medium - $138.00 USD</option>'''

url = "https://us.octobersveryown.com/collections/shop-all/products/varsity-ovo-polartec-half-zip-pullover-black"

def getStuff():
    print ('')
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(url)
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
prod_name = soup.find('h1',{'itemprop':'name'}).text
price = soup.find('span',{'id':'ProductPrice'}).text
variant = soup.find(text=size).findPrevious('value').text
#variant ="notworking"
print("\nProd Name: "+prod_name)
print("\nPrice: "+price)
print("\nMatching Variant Value: "+variant)

getStuff()
```

My error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trythis.py", line 20, in <module>
    variant = soup.find(text=size).findPrevious('value').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Since you are trying to match a word in the text of an `option` tag and get an attribute from that tag, I would do something like this:

```
import requests, re, json, time, sys, os,webbrowser
import subprocess as s
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
global size

size = "Medium"

html  = """<option selected="selected" data-sku="51728-003" value="660654030868">Medium - $138.00 USD</option>"""

url = "https://us.octobersveryown.com/collections/shop-all/products/varsity-ovo-polartec-half-zip-pullover-black"

def getStuff():
    print ('')
    session = requests.session()
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
    prod_name = soup.find('h1',{'itemprop':'name'}).text
    price = soup.find('span',{'id':'ProductPrice'}).text
    #variant = soup.find(text=size).findPrevious('value').text
    def get_option(size):
        options = soup.find_all('option')
        target_option = [o for o in options if size in o.text][0]
        value = target_option['value']
        return value
    def get_options_and_values():
        option_dic = {}
        options = soup.find_all('option')
        for o in options:
            try:
                option_dic[o.text.split('-')[0].strip()] = int(o['value'])
            except:
                pass
        return option_dic
    print(get_options_and_values())
    print("\nProd Name: "+prod_name)
    print("\nPrice: "+price.strip())
    variant = get_option(size)
    print("\nMatching Variant Value: "+variant)

getStuff()
```

This gives me:

```
{'Medium': 660654030868, 'Large': 660654063636}

Prod Name: VARSITY OVO POLARTEC® HALF-ZIP PULLOVER - BLACK

Price: $138.00

Matching Variant Value: 660654030868
```

This would allow you to change the size you want to get easily. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you for this! One last additional question, how could we set it as a loop function? Say, other options are not available yet, but we want the function to sleep and then try again. Would we use a while or for loop for get_option(size)?

Comment: cool. sure, see the edits I just made. You may want to handle "Sold Out" options differently. You just need to make sure that what you want to scrape has a consistent structure.